# how to append multiple dates in text area using JQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have an issues in JQuery datepicker, I need to append dates with past selected dates and want to show on textarea.

Date Selection Area:

```
<input type="text" id="selectdate">
```

My jQuery:

```
$( "#selectdate" ).datepicker({
    altField: "#dates",
    numberOfMonths:3,
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: -0,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {    
       $("#selectdate").val('');
       $('#dates').append(selectedDate);
    }
});

<textarea name="dates" id="dates">date will show here</textarea>
```

I need to show dates in textarea like `2013-05-11`,`2013-05-12`,`2013-05-13`

hope everyone understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$('#dates').val($('#dates').val()+','+selectedDate);
```

instead of

```
 $('#dates').append(selectedDate);
```

> Explanation

```
$('#dates').val(); //gets value element with id dates
$('#dates').val(value); //sets value for element with id dates
```

References

[**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: @NoorKhan can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: resolved $( "#selectdate" ).datepicker({
     //altField: "#dates",
     numberOfMonths:3,
     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
     altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
     minDate: -0,
     onSelect: function( selectedDate ) { 
     $("#selectdate").val('');
     if($('#dates').val()!='')
     {
      $('#dates').val($('#dates').val()+','+selectedDate);
     }
     else
     {
      $('#dates').val(selectedDate);
     }
    }
   });